# convergence of sequences $|a_{n}-L|<1/n$

Tags: convergence-divergence

$a_{n}=\frac{5n}{4n-3}$ , $L=5/4$
show that for all $n>12$ , $|a_{n}-L|<1/n$.

right now, I have:
$a_{n}-L=\frac{15}{4(4n-3)}<\frac{4}{4n-3}$ since $15/4=3.75<4$
    then I know $\frac{4}{4n-3} > 4/4n=1/n$ since $4n-3<n$
but this is a contradiction to what I need to prove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\dfrac{15}{16n-12}\le \frac{1}{n}$$ for all $n\ge 12.$

Comment: how to prove this statement?

Comment: cross multiplication!!

Comment: how stupid I am... sorry being messing around by formulas..lol